# How to configure reference to be deleted on parent table update?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, reference, foreign-keys

I have two tables:

```
info: ID, fee_id
```

and

```
fee: ID, amount
```

and a reference between them (`SQL Server 2008`):

```
ALTER TABLE info WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT FK_info_fee FOREIGN KEY(fee_id)
REFERENCES fee (ID)
ALTER TABLE info CHECK CONSTRAINT FK_info_fee
GO
```

How to configure this reference that way so a record in `fee` will be deleted if `info.fee_id` becomes `NULL`

**EDIT:** or maybe set `info.fee_id` to `NULL` on deleting the corresponding record in `fee`.

Anyway I can do it this way:

```
UPDATE info SET fee = NULL WHERE = ..
DELETE FROM fee WHERE ..
```

but I'm sure that this can be done by the database itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some thoughts:

- If you have a one:one reference then can the 2 tables be combined?
- Drilling up from child to parent is odd: if it's 1:1 then can you reverse the FK direction and simply CASCADE NULL?
- Otherwise, you'll have to use a trigger but assuming 1:1 makes me uneasy...
- ... unless you have a unique constraint/index on `info_fee.fee_id`

Like so:

```
ALTER TABLE info WITH CHECK ADD
CONSTRAINT FK_fee_info_fee FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES info_fee (fee_ID) ON DELETE SET NULL
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems to be useful! One question: as far as I could understand, in this configuration I have to delete `fee` and appropriate column in `info` will be NULLed automatically. Right?

Comment: Yesm, this is waht "ON DELETE SET NULL" does. On parent delete, a child row via the FK is set null

Comment: Oh no. That is not what I need. Parent record must exists always. Child one can be deleted and `info.fee_id` must be NULLed (in any order of this 2 operations). Is it possible using `REFERENCE`? Or only using `TRIGGER`?

Comment: You question says "How to configure this reference that way so a record in fee will be deleted"?

Comment: Yea! Record in `fee` (which is child) must be deleted when record in `info` (which is parent) is update

Comment: I tried and it does what I need - set NULL in parent record on child deletion

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't want to do this.  What would you expect to happen if multiple `info` rows referenced the same `fee` row?

If you really want to do something like this, adding logic to an [AFTER UPDATE, DELETE trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) on the info table would probably be the way to go.  Check if any other `info` rows reference that same `fee` row, and if not, delete the `fee` row.

Comment: I have one to one reference, i.e. only one record in `fee` is pointing to `info`.

Comment: @abatishchev: do you have database logic constraining the `fee` table to contain only one reference to each `info` row?  If you don't, sooner or later, you're going to get multiple references.

Comment: My table `fee` in production has also column `amount` and holds the data for 'invite-a-friend'. So constraining not via database logic but real-life business logic :) Only one client can invite a new one.

Answer (score 0):

If you really intend to remove rows when `fee_id` is set to null, one way is an `update` trigger.  In an update trigger, the `deleted` table contains the old version of the updated rows, and the `inserted` table contains the new version.  By joining them, you can take action when a fee_id changes to `null`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER deleteFee
ON info
FOR UPDATE
AS
    DELETE FROM Fee 
    WHERE Fee.id IN (
        SELECT old.fee_id 
        FROM deleted old
        JOIN inserted new ON old.id = new.id
        WHERE old.fee_id = fee.id 
        AND new.fee_id is null
    )
```

This is tricky when multiple info rows refer to the same fee.  The fee will be removed if any info row is set to null.  A full synch trigger would avoid that:

```
CREATE TRIGGER deleteFee
ON info
FOR UPDATE
AS
    DELETE FROM Fee 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM Info
        WHERE Fee.id = Info.fee_id
    )
```

But this can have other unintended consequences, like deleting half the Fee table in response to an update.  In this case, as in most cases, triggers add more complexity than they solve.  Triggers are evil and should be avoided at almost any cost.

Comment: A delete cascade would go the other way: delete `info` rows if a `fee` row is deleted, would it not?

Comment: @Michael Petrotta: You're right, I've removed the cascase, I'll upvote your answer :)